# Github: What happens to forks when a repository is renamed?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Additionally, what happens to the rest of the social creds and links:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Forks don’t get renamed, but maintain their relationship with the parent repo. Watches and stars are preserved. “Used by” should stay the same since it’s usually based off of package information *inside* the repository to begin with, and GitHub URL dependencies should follow the redirect that gets created by the rename, but I’ve never experienced it directly so I don’t know for sure.